# Attempting to deactivate a non-dynamic body

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sigabrt, chipmunk, spritebuilder

I am using Cocos2D 3.1 with SpriteBuilder and I am simply trying to get things working. I have set up my SpriteBuilder ccb with a physicsNode and put my physics objects within it.

In my app I then try to call this:

```
[_sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(-95.0f, 2800.0f)];
```

All of a sudden, there is a SIGABRT and it crashes on this line in cpSpaceComponent.c:

```
cpAssertHard(cpBodyGetType(body) == CP_BODY_TYPE_DYNAMIC, "Internal error: Attempting to deactivate a non-dynamic body.");
```

> Aborting due to Chipmunk error: Internal error: Attempting to
>   deactivate a non-dynamic body.    Failed condition: cpBodyGetType(body)
>   == CP_BODY_TYPE_DYNAMIC

I have looked around and there is no documentation on this type of crash. I am not even sure where to begin to try to fix this. Does anyone know what I should do to fix this crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out my CCPhysicsNode had a sleep time threshold of 0, once I set it to the normal .5, everything works fine.